# cakephp 2.2.2 pagination search condition

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to add pagination in CakePHP 2.x with condition search in a form. However, in the View it doesn't give the next page with my condition. Here is my code:

Controller

```
public function result($palabraclave = null)
    {
      $this->layout = 'tempart';
          $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 5,
            'order' => array(
                'Articulo.created' => 'desc'),
                'conditions'=>array("titulo like ?"=>"%".$this->data['Paginas']['palabraclave']."%") 
        )
       $data = $this->paginate('Articulo');//Consulta a la base de datos
        $this->set(compact('data'));
    }
```

---

If I click "next" to see the next page result of the search, it doesn't pass on the pagination condition from page 1 to page 2. :(

View:

```
    <div style="display: inline-block;  width:70%;" id="test">
<?php foreach ($data as $da): ?>

<br />

<article>   
<?php echo $this->Html->image('article_preview/mini_'.$da['Articulo']['imagen'], array('alt' => 'Hospital-Excel'))?>
<div style="text-align:left;">
<?php echo $this->Html->link("<h6 class='artnombre'>".$da['Articulo']['titulo']."<h6>", array('class'=>"artnombre",'action'=> 'articulo',$da['Articulo']['id']),array('escape' => false)); ?> 

</div>
<br />
<p> 
<?php echo $da['Articulo']['descripcion']; ?>               <?php echo $this->Html->link('Read more ....', array('action'=> 'articulo',$da['Articulo']['id'])); ?>  
<h5></h5>
</p>
<div class="puntoshorizontal" style="clear"></div>
</article>  
<?php endforeach; ?>



<div style="text-align:center">
<?php
// Shows the page numbers
// Shows the next and previous links
echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Back', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')) . " |";
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(). "| "; 
echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
echo "<br />";
echo $this->Paginator->counter();
// prints X of Y, where X is current page and Y is number of pages


?>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: try to debug $this->data['Paginas']['palabraclave'];

Comment: is the `?` after `titulo like` supposed to be there?

Comment: Look at your SQL log to see the query even works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way to persist your search params on each page you should do the following:
After you post data, in your method you have $this->data['Paginas']['palabraClave'] then save it the the session. So in each subsequent call to /resultados/pag1,2,..n you get the value of palabra clave from the session.

Finally you would get something like:

```
public function resultados(){
    $conditions = array();

    if($this->Session->check('conditions')){
      $conditions = $this->Session->read('conditions');
    }

    if(isset($this->data)){
        $conditions = array("titulo LIKE" => "%".this->data['Paginas']'palabraclave']"%",));
    //save to the session
    $this->Session->write('conditions',$conditions);
    }
    $data = $this->painate('Articulo',$conditions);
    $this->set('data');
}
```

This may need some adjust but the idea I think is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Set your paginate conditions when calling the paginate method, like this:

```
$data = $this->paginate('Articulo', array(
    "titulo LIKE" => "%" . $this->data['Paginas']['palabraclave'] . "%",
));
```

as opposed to in the paginate property.

Comment: in That phace is working good the problem is wen i click in the next buton sorry me english is bad

Comment: Try adding `<?php debug($this->Paginator->params()); ?>` to your view to see what params are being passed to the paginator. Your above view code and next link should work.

Answer (score 0):

this is example:

1: pass all URL arguments to paginator functions

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

2: Common mistake: not keep condition search with paginate

```
if($this->data){
    $this->passedArgs = array(
       'name' => $this->data[‘User’]['name']
    );
}else{
    if(isset($this->passedArgs['name'])){
         $this->data[‘User’]['name'] = $this->passedArgs['name'];
    }else{
         $this->data[‘User’]['name'] = ;
    }
}
```